# An unhandled exception occurred: The requested module '@angular/compiler' does not provide an export named 'R3SelectorScopeMode

Tags: javascript

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QbNES.jpg)   this error occured when i'm trying to make this command : npm start , in order to run my project (with json-server and json-server-auth), is there someone who could help me in this issue, thanks. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXGh6.jpg)